# Java Generics: how to solve warning on call to JComboBox.setRenderer

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

Coming back to Java after a multi-year hiatus, and partway through adding some code to an inhouse library.  The class in question is an extension of JComboBox, which ensures that disabled items are greyed out and unselectable.  Some of the code is based on that found at https://www.algosome.com/articles/enable-disable-jcombobox.html.  The idea is that we have (1) a data model which ensures that only enabled items may be selected, and (2) a custom renderer which shows disabled items greyed out:

[image]

[image]

The code is working, but the compiler isn't completely happy with my generics.  I'd really rather have a happy compiler, but I'm out of ideas as to how to achieve that in this case.  Below is an SSCCE, which produces the above combo box.  My apologies for the length; this really is the shortest I could get it.  The outer class contains several inner classes; all the classes that will live in the library have `Lib` prepended to their names; `MyComboBox` is simply there to demonstrate the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    //--------------------LIB CB ITEM--------------------------------------------------
    private class LibCBItem extends JMenuItem
    {
        private LibCB myComboBox;

        LibCBItem(String title, LibCB parent)
        {
            super(title);
            myComboBox = parent;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean b)
        {
            boolean changeSelection = false;

            if (!b && isEnabled() && this.equals(myComboBox.getSelectedItem())) {
                int enabledCount = myComboBox.getEnabledItemCount();
                if (enabledCount == 2)
                    changeSelection = true;
                else if (enabledCount == 1)
                    System.out.println("setEnabled(FALSE) on final remaining enabled item");
                else
                    System.out.println("setEnabled(FALSE) of selected item with " + enabledCount + " enabled items: must change selection before disabling");
            }

            super.setEnabled(b);

            if (changeSelection)
                myComboBox.selectEnabledItem();
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return getText();
        }
    }

    //--------------------LIB CB DATA MODEL--------------------------------------------------
    private class LibCBDataModel<T extends LibCBItem> extends DefaultComboBoxModel<T>
    {
        public void setSelectedItem(Object o)
        {
            LibCBItem item = (LibCBItem) o;
            if (item != null) {
                if (item.isEnabled())
                    super.setSelectedItem(item);
            }
            else {
                super.setSelectedItem(null);
            }
        }
    }

    //--------------------LIB CB RENDERER--------------------------------------------------
    private class LibCBRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
    {
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {
            JLabel c = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            LibCBItem item = (LibCBItem) value;
            if (item.isEnabled()) {
                c.setBackground(super.getBackground());
                c.setForeground(super.getForeground());
                if (isSelected) // is the mouse over it?
                    c.setText("√ " + c.getText());
                else
                    c.setText("    " + c.getText());
            }
            else {
                if (isSelected) // is the mouse over it?
                    c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.background"));
                else
                    c.setBackground(super.getBackground());

                c.setForeground(Color.lightGray);

                c.setText("    " + c.getText());
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    //--------------------LIB CB--------------------------------------------------
    private class LibCB<T extends LibCBItem> extends JComboBox<T>
    {
        LibCB()
        {
            super();
            setModel(new LibCBDataModel<>());
            setRenderer(new LibCBRenderer());
            //Warning:(127, 36) java: unchecked method invocation: method setRenderer in class javax.swing.JComboBox is applied to given types
            //  required:
            //    javax.swing.ListCellRenderer<? super E>
            //  found:
            //    SSCCE.LibCBRenderer
            //Warning:(127, 37) java: unchecked conversion
            //  required:
            //    javax.swing.ListCellRenderer<? super E>
            //  found:
            //    SSCCE.LibCBRenderer
        }

        int getEnabledItemCount()
        {
            int returnVal = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (getItemAt(i).isEnabled())
                    returnVal++;
            }
            return returnVal;
        }

        void selectEnabledItem()
        {
            boolean selectedOne = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (getItemAt(i).isEnabled()) {
                    setSelectedIndex(i);
                    selectedOne = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!selectedOne)
                System.out.println("selectEnabledItem() with 0 enabled items in combo box");
        }
    }

    //--------------------MY COMBO BOX--------------------------------------------------
    private class MyComboBox extends LibCB<LibCBItem>
    {
        MyComboBox()
        {
            LibCBItem item1 = new LibCBItem("1st", this);
            addItem(item1);
            LibCBItem item2 = new LibCBItem("2nd", this);
            addItem(item2);
            LibCBItem item3 = new LibCBItem("3rd", this);
            addItem(item3);

            item2.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    //--------------------SSCCE--------------------------------------------------
    SSCCE()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.add(new MyComboBox());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SSCCE());
    }
}
```

The compiler is giving me two warnings on the same line, in `LibCB()` where it calls `JComboBox.setRenderer()`.  I've pasted the text of the warnings inline.  Here it is for ease of reference:

```
Warning:(127, 36) java: unchecked method invocation: method setRenderer in class javax.swing.JComboBox is applied to given types
  required:
    javax.swing.ListCellRenderer<? super E>
  found:
    SSCCE.LibCBRenderer
Warning:(127, 37) java: unchecked conversion
  required:
    javax.swing.ListCellRenderer<? super E>
  found:
    SSCCE.LibCBRenderer
```

Is someone able to point me in the direction of resolving these and getting the compiler happy?  Java 8, in case it makes a difference.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is inside of `BasicComboBoxRenderer`, because that class hasn't generic parameter for `ListCellRenderer` interface, but `JComboBox` class expects generalized `aRenderer` variable, see snippet:

```
    public void setRenderer(ListCellRenderer<? super E> aRenderer) {
        ListCellRenderer<? super E> oldRenderer = renderer;
        renderer = aRenderer;
        firePropertyChange( "renderer", oldRenderer, renderer );
        invalidate();
    }
```

As workaround I can propose to copy all logic from `BasicComboBoxRenderer` to you own custom class and add generic type for `ListCellRenderer`, and that approcu will solve warning during compilation process.